# How to get a list of all objects contained in my different QGis layers

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql, pyqgis

I would like to know how we could do in QGis to get a list of object contained in my different opened layers:
We have n .SHP files or PostgreSQL Views (they all contain at least an "object type" column and an "object id" column) opened in a QGis Project to make a map.
When the map is done, I want to save my .QGS file on a server and then I want (by a Python program ?) to get a .CSV file with 3 columns (object type, object id, path of my .QGS file) - or even better to write the data directly into PostgreSQL.

Does anybody ses how to make that easily on QGis ?

Comment: I wanted to say .QGS file (we planned at the bennining to work with MapInfo where projects are .WOR, I haven't change all extensions in my new post, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

Before you start you will want to decide what will be the "target", a file or a database. A file is a tiny bit simpler though psycopg2 makes handling postgres databases very easy as well.

```
with open('/home/you/data/out.csv', 'w') as f:
```

First you want to get a list of layers

```
    map_layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
```

Then you want to iterate over every feature in each layer

```
    for layer in map_layers.values():
        for feat in layer.getFeatures():
```

And finally write whatever you want into the file:

```
            f.write('{}, {}, {}\n'.format(feat['object_type'], feat['object_id'], wor_file??))
```